# Removing text from string starting and ending with special chracter

Tags: java, string

i have a string like "Hi ${CUSTOMER_NAME} your address is ${CUSTOMER_ADDRESS} 
".
I need to remove every text which starts with $and ends with }. so the output of above should be like Hi Your address is.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try to use [indexOf()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm) and [substring()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get your solution.

Comment: it can be a long string so using indexOf will not be a good solution

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use regex, here is an example you can use:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){
        String regex = "(\\$\\{\\w+\\})";
        String str = "Hi ${CUSTOMER_NAME} your address is ${CUSTOMER_ADDRESS}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex); 
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(str);
        String replaceAll = matcher.replaceAll("");
        System.out.println(str);
        System.out.println(replaceAll);
     }
}
```

You are welcome to read more about [regex and metcher](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-regex/matcher.html#replaceall-replacefirst-methods).

Hope this helps